# Как правильно подключить api?

Tags: php, ajax, api

У меня на сайте есть форма заполнения, в поле Счет-фактура я должен ввести номер счета например `111111-11`, после проверки, если счет правильный он мне должен вывести `СЧ-111111-11`, в ином случае должен выводить

> "Проверьте корректность введённого Счёта:

форма заполнения выглядит так:

```
    form class="form1" action="index.php">

    <label class="label2"><?php echo _("№ Счёта на оплату");?></label>
   <input class=" field only-numeric input1" type="text" name="invoice" value="">
```

в `index.php`

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 0);
header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time()-3600) . " GMT");
header( "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
session_start();

include("../engine/api.php");
//include("../vendor/utils.php");

$api=new api();
//$utils=new utils();
$api->test=0;



/* ======================= getinvoice =================================== */
$url = "getinvoice/";
$api->post = array(
    'invoice' => 'СЧ-111111/11',

);
$vehicle = $api->sendrequest($url);
echo '<details><summary>getinvoice</summary>';
echo '<p><pre>';
print_r($api->post);
print_r($vehicle);
echo '</pre></p></details>';
exit;
```

когда нажимаю на сабмит, то обработчик должен взять информацию из `index.php`, то есть номер счета `111111-11`, помогите реализовать эту функцию

Comment: Наше сообщество помогает тем, кто помогают сами себе. За вас не будут делать вашу работу, но помогут с конкретным вопросом или разъяснением. Напишите функцию, и если что-то где-то будет непонятно - вот тогда и задавайте вопрос.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я не прошу написать за меня код, я прошу помочь реализовать эту функцию, что именно надо написать, через что лучше реализовывать, и т д?

Comment: Прочитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask о том, как лучше задавать вопрос, на который у вас будет больше шансов получить ответ. Ваш вопрос подразумевает несколько абстрактных вещей сразу (что и как), которые могут интерпретироваться по разному. Также, как уже было сказано, это будет означать необходимость думать за вас, вместо того чтобы дать вам возможность прийти к нужному решению через подсказку, а не через решение целиком.